# How to compare the textures in LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I am using LibGdx for my game. In the below method I am passing the RED_BALL but the method is not returning true. I want to know if the texture comparision is possible. if so what is the best approach.

```
private boolean isSqueezableBalls(Texture t) {
    if(t.equals(RED_BALL) || 
            t.equals(BLUE_BALL) || 
                t.equals(GREEN_BALL)){ 
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Textures are resources, you probably want to compare them by reference. Btw, you probably don't want to use statics for resources and you likely want to pack multiple image into a single texture and use TextureRegion instead of Texture directly.

Comment: The Texture class doesn't override `.equals` so you may as well be using `==`. It's only testing for the same reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to develop a more OOP coding habbit.
Then you could add a texture to a class and when you need to compare it there will be no problems. You can later simply check the instance.

```
 class Ball {
        // Ball Data

        public Ball() {
            // ADD LOGIC
        }
    }

    class GreenBall extends Ball {

        public GreenBall() {
            super();
            // ADD LOGIC
        }
    }

    class RedBall extends Ball {

        public RedBall() {
            super();
            //ADD LOGIC
        }
```

So you could have a method like:

```
private void isSquizableBall(Ball b) {
    if(b instanceof GreenBall){ 
        System.out.print("It's a green ball");

    } else if(b instanceof RedBall){ 
        System.out.print("It's a green ball");
    }
}
```